# Access to class method from other class method

Tags: c#

I have a class of fonts like:

```
namespace Project.Utility
{
  public class Fonts
    {
        public Font TitleFont()
        {
            var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            return font;
        }

        public Font SubtitleFont()
        {
            var font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
            return font;
        }

        public Font TotalMinutesFont()
        {
            var font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            return font;
        }
    }
}
```

So into another class I want to call font method like this:

```
 using Project.Utility;

 private void MyMethod(){

                  title.Font = Fonts.TitleFont;
                        }
```

But I don't have access to `.TitleFont` How can I call it in order to access to this method? Regards

Comment: Assuming your example isn't contrived, the problem is that the class Fonts and/or the TitleFont method isn't static. Therefore, you need an instance in order to access TitleFont. The TitleFont method is public and the class is public; therefore, you should have access to it (presuming it's in the same or a referenced assembly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what I stated in my comment and what Piotr started in his answer. I would recommend changing the `Fonts` class to static (since all its methods have no reliance on state).

```
public static class Fonts
{
    public static Font TitleFont()
    {
        var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        return font;
    }

    public static Font SubtitleFont()
    {
        var font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
        return font;
    }

    public static Font TotalMinutesFont()
    {
        var font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
        return font;
    }
}
```

You can then access the methods like `Fonts` using the syntax you provided in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Make the method `TitleFont` static

```
public static Font TitleFont()
{
    return new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

And then do:

```
using Project.Utility;

private void MyMethod(){
              title.Font = Fonts.TitleFont();
                    }
```

Comment: Or use an instance of your Fonts class to access them. If they're not static, they are considered instance members